# How to select an image from the gallery in a jetpack compose test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-gallery, android-jetpack-compose-testing

I have a composable that opens the gallery and selects an image to display to the user. I'd like to test this functionality but composeTestRule doesn't have access to the gallery. I would like to mock out the intent like what is done with espresso `intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)).respondWith(activityResult)`. Is there something similar for Jetpack Compose? How do I select an image from the gallery in a Jetpack Compose test?

```
// PictureSelector.kt

@Composable
fun PictureSelector() {
    val (galleryImage, setGalleryImage) = remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    val galleryLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            onResult = setGalleryImage,
        )
    if (galleryImage == null) {
        TextButton(onClick = { galleryLauncher.launch("image/*") }) {
            Text("Add image")
        }
    } else {
        AsyncImage(model = galleryImage, contentDescription = "Picture")
    }
}

// PictureSelectorTest.kt

class PictureSelectorTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun onClick_selectsPicture() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            PictureSelector()
        }

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Add image").performClick()

        // How do I select an image from the gallery?

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription("Picture").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```